# wxPython - Manually resize interior sizer

Tags: wxpython

I want to add multiple sizers to a frame and make them manually resizeable so that the user can arrange the layout according to his preferences. Of course, I'm able to resize the whole frame but I also want to resize the interior divisions. This is my code:

```
    logsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    logsizer.Add(self.log, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    eventsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    eventsizer.Add(self.eventarea, 0, wx.EXPAND)

    self.gridSizer.Add(logsizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.gridSizer.Add(eventsizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
```

Is there any way to declare my sizers as "manually resizable"

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A sizer is not manually resizeable. You could use AUI and manage several windows that way. AUI allows some GUI rearrangement. I recommend the wx.agw.aui over wx.aui because it's pure Python and less buggy, or so I'm told.